# 3D Cursor follows Mouse Movement

Tags: modeling, selection-tools, 3d-cursor

[image: The cursor that I have circled follows all my movements]

The 3D cursor follows me everywhere and does not let me select any other tool.

In my scenario, when I use the edit mode, the 3d cursor doesn't let me select the vertices,edges or faces.

I am beginner and help is appreciated!
**Thank you!**

Comment: In this case especially everything depends on Blender version you use. It looks from the screenshot and video this is 2.79 version. There default is right click select. Left click moves 3d cursor. It can be changed to vice versa in User prefs though I would highly recommend to leave it as is in 2.79 since there might be some conflicts in other shortcuts.

Comment: @MrZak Thank you very much and yes indeed it is version 2.79. Do you suggest using 2.79 or 2.80 beta?

Comment: If you have decent hardware and plan on using Blender further on then get experience with 2.8 as it's version which will be updated and developed. Do not try it on any important files though as 2.8 is still beta and isn't fully compatible with 2.79. Note this depends quite  abit on tasks you plan to solve; if you need to discuss that I suggest blenderartists.org instead.

Comment: @MrZak Alright, thank you very much once again for your support!

Answer (score 1):

As Chaola said, probably you are trying to select the edges with the left-mouse button. To change this preference:

- go to **File > User Preferences** (or use the shortcut **Ctrl + Alt + U**)
- move to **Input section**
- in the left side you can choose what mouse button you want to use to select objects

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Blender, you have to use right click to select. Left click move the 3d cursor. 
This can be change in the User Settings, under the "Input" tab.

Comment: I am still unable to select the edges. Check out this link to see exactly what the problem is : http://bit.ly/2v0EbXb

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to go about changing settings in the user settings?